# How to share image and text with custom formatting?

Tags: android

I am able to share image and multiple text using the following code:

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("*/*");
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
try {
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "this is subject");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "HeadLine.\nIntroText");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
        Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/temporary_file.jpg"));

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

I tested it in whatsapp share and it is working. Here is the current share output:

```
-->> Image display 
-->> Subject display
-->> Extra text display
```

But I am using custom formatting and it is not working. Here is the custom formatting:

```
-->> Image display in left side with 20*20 -->> Subject display in right side
     -->> Extra text display in right side
```

Can this be done?